# Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined (anonymous function) $(function() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-datepicker { font-size: 62.5%; }
    </style>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
        $("#EndDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
    });
    </script>
 </head>
  <body bgcolor='#6a7c99'>
<input id='StartDate' type='text' style='position:absolute;top:35px;left:92px;width:55px;font-family:arial narrow;font-size:8pt;display:none;' name='StartDate'>
  <input id='EndDate' type='text' style='position:absolute;top:75px;left:92px;width:55px;font-family:arial narrow;font-size:8pt;display:none;' name='EndDate'>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code does not work. $function() does not work and throws an error. Whats wrong? What other jQuery libraries should be included?

Comment: jQuery was not properly loaded

Comment: Change `https://` to `//` and it should work fine. Your protocols are probably mismatched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the links for [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) and [jquery ui](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js) are throwing a 504. Hence the error. 
`https://` does not work.

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: https does not work either, since my server is secured and has SSL certificate it blocks any http. However $(document).ready(function()) works fine. Please suggest me what to do!

Comment: Please suggest how to use jquery and jquery ui links in a secured server!

Comment: That is exactly what I told you. Download all the files into a folder where you have your static files. If you don't create a new one. And point to that instead of the current link you are using